# How do I validate using the Netbeans's Validation API

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, validation

I am using Netbeans Validation API. The documentation can be found in this link. I am trying to validate a bunch of text fields, so I have a class that implements the `DocumentListener` interface and then my swing components in another view class.

Here is a code snippet

```
@Override
public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
        checkValidation();
    }
@Override
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
        checkValidation();
}
@Override
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
        checkValidation();
}
private void checkValidation() {
    Problem validateAll = l.getGroup().performValidation();
        if (validateAll.isFatal()) {
            l.getLogin().setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            l.getLogin().setEnabled(true);
        }
```

**And here is the snippet of the view**

`username = new JTextField();
    username.setName("Username");
    username.getDocument().addDocumentListener(lc);
    username.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(12, 35));
    panel.add(username, "7, 6, 5, 1, fill, fill");
    username.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password:");
    panel.add(lblPassword, "4, 10");

    password = new JTextField();
    password.setName("Password");
    password.getDocument().addDocumentListener(lc);
    password.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(12, 35));
    panel.add(password, "7, 10, 5, 1, fill, default");
    password.setColumns(10);

    login = new JButton("Login");
    login.setEnabled(false);
    login.addActionListener(lc);
    panel.add(login, "7, 14, 2, 1, fill, default");

    JButton forgotLogin = new JButton("Forgot Login Details");
    forgotLogin.setActionCommand("Forgot Login");
    forgotLogin.addActionListener(lc);
    forgotLogin.setSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
    panel.add(forgotLogin, "10, 14, fill, default");

    ValidationPanel xpanel = new ValidationPanel();
    xpanel.setInnerComponent(panel);
    group = xpanel.getValidationGroup();
    group.add(username, StringValidators.REQUIRE_NON_EMPTY_STRING,
            StringValidators.NO_WHITESPACE);
     group.add(password,
     StringValidators.REQUIRE_NON_EMPTY_STRING,StringValidators.NO_WHITESPACE);
    contentPane.add(xpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);`

I get errors with with code. I get a `NullPointerPointerException`. How do I validate these two fields by specifying a group and validators in one class and then implementing a DocumentListener in another class. Is there any other way I could validate the two text fields?

Comment: If you are getting a NPE, then for the best help, post the stacktrace and indicate which line throws the NPE.

Comment: This is the kine that throws the NPE - Problem validateAll = l.getGroup().performValidation();

Comment: So either `l` is null, or the object returned by `l.getGroup()` is null, and this should be easy for you to check. Which is it?